# php mysql where part of column value only

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to delete a column in php mysql on the condition that when part of the string of the column is a match

My query is

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM User_tbl WHERE name ");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Sample value for column name is

```
John|Smith|Jr
```

I want check the middle part if a match. So want to check like this

`Where the middlepart of the name is  = Smith`

Comment: `WHERE name like '%|Smith|%'`

Comment: WHERE name LIKE '%|Smith|%`

Comment: hi guys i appreciate the response can you give it as answer and explain a bit what happened. it would be nice if i know what i did and what happened

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM User_tbl WHERE name like '%Smith%'
```

you can use like with finish sentence

'%some text' -> 'my string has some text'

```
select * from table where field like '%some text'
```

start sentence

'some text%' -> 'some text has my string'

```
select * from table where field like 'some text%'
```

or both

'%some text%' -> 'my string has some text to search'

```
select * from table where field like '%some text%'
```